# How can I create a jquery function involving 3 divs?

Tags: jquery, function, html

I need some help creating a function which does the same thing for the chosen elements.

I have #design1 #design1servicetext and #design1servicebutton.

Code:

```
//Service hover//
$('#design1').mouseenter(function (){
    $('#design1servicetext').css('background-position', '0 -91px')  
    $('#design1servicebutton').css('background-position', '0 -33px')
    })
               .mouseleave(function (){
    $('#design1servicetext').css('background-position', '0 0px')
    $('#design1servicebutton').css('background-position', '0 0px')});
//Service hover end//
```

How can I create a function, in which I have to choose 3 divs to do the animation?

I want a function like

```
animatebg('#design1','#design1servicetext','#design1servicebutton');
```

Can someone please help me? I've tried so many function tutorials but none of them worked for what I wanted to do. Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: Do you want the animation to trigger on all of the chosen elements as soon as you hover your mouse over just one of them or should the animation trigger only on the one that you hover your mouse over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, try this:

```
function animatebg( jq1, jq2, jq3 ) {
    $('#'+jq1).mouseenter(function() {
        $('#'+jq2).css('background-position', '0 -91px')  
        $('#'+jq3).css('background-position', '0 -33px')
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $('#'+jq2).css('background-position', '0 0px')
        $('#'+jq3).css('background-position', '0 0px')});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function animatebg(param1,param2,param3){
    $("#"+param1).mouseenter(function (){
    $("#"+param2).css('background-position', '0 -91px')  
    $("#"+param3).css('background-position', '0 -33px')
    })
               .mouseleave(function (){
    $("#"+param2).css('background-position', '0 0px')
    $("#"+param3).css('background-position', '0 0px')});
}
```

Comment: haha, why did you start with ' and end with " on your pound selector?

Answer (score 0):

I did a infinite argument function, so you can have less or more selectors, please see the link for full example http://jsfiddle.net/AcUCm/

Here with my function:

```
function animatebg() {
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            var val = arguments[i].toString();

            $(val).live('mouseenter', function() {
                $(this).css('background-position', '0 -91px')
                $(this).css('background-position', '0 -33px')
            }).live('mouseleave', function() {
                $(this).css('background-position', '0 0px')
                $(this).css('background-position', '0 0px')
            });

        }
}
```

Usage (document ready)

```
$(function() {
animatebg('#design1', '#design1servicetext', '#design1servicebutton');
});
```

Comment: This isn't what I asked for. Thank you though.

Comment: No problem, made it a bit more dynamic in case your scenario changes. Pleasure